# Custom message when Disabled login through login.salesforce.com

Tags: login, user-admin

We have disabled users login through https://login.salesforce.com and now only allow SSO login, but to avoid confusion we want to provide custom message when they try to login through https://login.salesforce.com currently standard message may confuse users.

Answer (score 0):

You can't override standard error message but you can show informative details related to login process in right side panel on login screen.

Comment: I guess customized right panel only appears when we use my domain.